# Python & nose: what is the variable scope in the "test class"?

Tags: python-2.7, nose, nosetests

I am running tests with nose and would like to use a variable from one of the tests item in another. For this I create the variable when setting the class up. It seems to me that the variable is copied for each item, so the one in the class stays in fact untouched. If instead of a simple variable I use a list, I see the behavior that I was expecting.

I wrote a small exemple, we can observe that `var1` and `varg` always show the same value when entering a test:

```
import time
import sys
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger('008')


class Test008:
    varg = None

    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        logger.info('* setup class')
        cls.var1 = None
        cls.list1 = []

    def setup(self):
        logger.info('\r\n* setup')
        logger.info('\t var1: {}, varg: {}, list: {}'.format(
            self.var1, self.varg, self.list1))

    def teardown(self):
        logger.info('* teardown')
        logger.info('\t var1: {}, varg: {}, list: {}'.format(
            self.var1, self.varg, self.list1))

    def test_000(self):
        self.var1 = 0
        self.varg = 0
        self.list1.append(0)
        pass

    def test_001(self):
        # Here I would like to access the variables but they still show 'None'
        self.var1 = 1
        self.varg = 1
        self.list1.append(1)
        pass

    @classmethod
    def teardown_class(self):
        logger.info('* teardown class')
```

Result:

```
nose.config: INFO: Ignoring files matching ['^\\.', '^_', '^setup\\.py$']
* setup class
008_TestVars.Test008.test_000 ... 
* setup
     var1: None, varg: None, list: []
* teardown
     var1: 0, varg: 0, list: [0]
ok

008_TestVars.Test008.test_001 ... 
* setup
     var1: None, varg: None, list: [0]
* teardown
     var1: 1, varg: 1, list: [0, 1]
ok
* teardown class

----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there a way to have the values of `var1` and `varg` be carried on from one test to the other?

Comment: Before I answer this question, tell me why you want to do this - if you make tests rely on data from previous tests they are not unit tests (which may be fine), you probably have to run them in a known order (which misses some of the feedback tests can give you. Why do you feel the need to do this?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I have to repeat a command with the same parameters to see that it is rejected the second time. So I write the test a second time with a different pass condition.

This first command is using the current time to fill one of the parameters sent. When sending the command in the second test, I want this exact same parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html#test-classes) clearly say

> a test case is constructed to run each method with a fresh instance of
>   the test class

If you need the actual time to set up an parameter to the function you are testing, why not write a test which sets up the state, call your function once and assert it passes then call it again and assert if fails?

```
def test_that_two_calls_to_my_method_with_same_params_fails(self):
    var1 = 1
    varg = 1
    assert myMethod(var1, varg)
    assert myMethod(var1, varg) == False
```

I think that is clearer because one test has all the state together, and can run the tests in any order.

You could argue it does, because you were trying to use the setup method. The docs also say

> A test module is a python module that matches the testMatch regular
>   expression. Test modules offer module-level setup and teardown; define
>   the method setup, setup_module, setUp or setUpModule for setup,
>   teardown, teardown_module, or tearDownModule for teardown.

So, outside your class have a

```
def setup_module()
    #bother now I need to use global variables
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks! I went for `yield` rather than assert to see the results separated.